# How to read XML string with PHP

Tags: php

Eg:

```
$xmlstr ='<Address><to>Sriniva</to><from>Chennai</from><country>India</county></Address>';

ReadXml($xmlstr)
```

**Output** ->

Address

to: Srinivas

from: Chennai

country : India

Answer (score 11):

With [SimpleXML](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

```
$address = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
printf("%s\nto: %s\nfrom: %s\ncountry: %s",
       $address->getName(),
       $address->to, 
       $address->from, 
       $address->country);
```

or

```
$address = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
echo $address->getName(), PHP_EOL;
foreach($address as $name => $part) {
    echo "$name: $part", PHP_EOL;
}
```

Both output:

```
Address
to: Sriniva
from: Chennai
country: India
```

Just fix the closing `country` tag. It has a typo and is missing the *r*.

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_string("<Address>;
<to>Srinivas</to>
<from>Chennai</from>
<country>India</country>
</Address> ");



echo $xml->getName() . "<br />";

foreach($xml->children() as $child)
  {
  echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "<br />";
  }
?>
```

Output:

Address

to: Srinivas

from: Chennai

country : India

Comment: If this is an addition to your question, please edit your original question instead of giving it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

you have an error in your xml string

> country tag is closed wrongly *county*

right xml

```
$xmlstr ='<Address><to>Sriniva</to><from>Chennai</from><country>India</country></Address>';
```

to change XML to array you can simply do this

```
$address = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);

    $address = json_encode($address);
    $address = json_decode($address, TRUE);
```

then with you can access $address as

```
echo $address["to"];
```

prints Sriniva

```
print_r($address)
```

prints

```
Array
(
   [to] => Sriniva
   [from] => Chennai
   [country] => India
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [XML functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php), but using [XSLT](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) would be another decent option.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to have a look to the PHP [**xpath**](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_simplexml_xpath.asp).

They use almost your same code in the example :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Xml is not Valid so, its not Possible to do it with the xml tools php provides.